# Laravel old input with group

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel to populate a list of products from the database.. Every product has it's own ID and belongs to a products[] array.

> Now I can't seem to retrieve the old input, It's always defaulting to the default value that I pass along, that is 0

This is the code I'm trying.. Maybe it has something to do with my parenthesis?

```
<input type="number" name="products[{{ $product->id }}]" value="{{ old('products[$product->id]', 0) }}" />
```

I've also tried with escaping the $product->id, still no success

```
<input type="number" name="products[{{ $product->id }}]" value="{{ old('products[' . $product->id . ']', 0) }}" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the old() method I found the solution, It's even easier then I tought.

```
value="{{ old('products.' . $product->id, 0) }}"
```

> So the solution is to use the dot operator to find the specific
>   product in the array of products

Full input code:

```
<input type="number" name="products[{{ $product->id }}]" value="{{ old('products.' . $product->id, 0) }}" />
```

Comment: Or you could use double quotes to enclose the string `old("products[$product->id]", 0)`.

Comment: Good comment @JohnBupit! Didn't think of that. Thanks!